# combine values with identical row labels but different prefixes - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['az_LC','bz_LC','ZG','az_KJ','bz_KJ'],'y':[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

I'd like to combine the values in `y` for identical combination of letters without the prefixes. For example there are two instances of `LC` with prefixes `az` and `bz`. I would like to combine the `y` values of `LC` into a list. The problem is that I have other combination of letters that don't have prefixes (like `ZG`). This is the desired output

```
   x    y
0  LC  [1,2]
1  ZG  [3]
2  KJ  [4,5]
```

EDIT: Some of my letter combinations include underscores, but they are still unique

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['az_LC','bz_LC','ZG','az_KJ','bz_KJ','U_FT'],'y':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

Desired output

```
   x      y
0  LC    [1,2]
1  ZG    [3]
2  KJ    [4,5]
3  U_FT  [6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC `str.split` with `pd.Series.groupby`

```
df.y.groupby(df.x.str.split('_').str[-1]).apply(list).reset_index()
Out[103]: 
    x       y
0  KJ  [4, 5]
1  LC  [1, 2]
2  ZG     [3]
```

---

Update

```
df1=df.loc[df.x.str.startswith(('az','bz'))]
df2=df.drop(df1.index)
s1=df1.y.groupby(df1.x.str.split('_',1).str[-1]).apply(list)
s2=df2.y.groupby(df2.x).apply(list)
df=pd.concat([s1,s2])
df
Out[113]: 
x
KJ      [4, 5]
LC      [1, 2]
U_FT       [6]
ZG         [3]
Name: y, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks @Wen-Ben, that's exactly it. However, I realized that some of my letter combinations use underscores even though they are unique. I edited my question with an example. In this case I'd like to keep the prefix since it's actually part of the name. Your code however eliminates everything before and including the underscore. How would you approach this problem?

Comment: @HappyPy that is hard , only if you know what is the perfix in the x , then we can split the dataframe , do it one by one

Comment: Thanks @Wen-Ben. I know that the prefixes I want to ignore are always `az` and `bz`. I'm just not sure how to tell pandas how to split according to some prefixes but not others... Do you mean doing it one by one as in a loop?

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense! Many thanks for your help again!